How can I get the IMediaWriter from Xuggler to work?
I'm trying to write a .mp4 file from multiple images using Xuggler. I found that you have to use the IMediaWriter class to do so. But trying to create an Object of that Class resulted in an Error.
I used the following line of code:
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;

final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("c:/test.mp4");

Using it threw the Error code:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<init>(JNIMemoryManager.java:861)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<clinit>(JNIMemoryManager.java:860)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
    at CreateVideo.main(CreateVideo.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more


Looks like you're missing a (transitive) dependency on that logging framework.  Do you use a build tool like Maven or Gradle? If not, I'd recommend you do. If you don't want to do that, you need to manually download such dependencies. With a build tool look up org.slf4j.LoggerFactory on Maven Central or such and add the dependency. Maybe file a bug report with xuggle to add the dependency.
